# Cant use weights inside of navigation drawer?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout-weight, navigation-drawer

Im working on a small converter just to get back into java i added a navigation drawer but the layout of the elements (buttons, textviews etc) werent setup very good so i decided to use weights but for some reason the weights make it look just fine in the xml preview however when i boot the app onto my phone it doesnt show any of the elements. The navigation drawer works just fine but again the elements nothings there, ive tried to fix it with no luck any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:weightSum="2">

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#121212"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.stiansformula.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/binarynumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:alpha="50"
        android:background="#222222"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textColorLink="#ffffff" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bnumtext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#232323"
        android:onClick="calculatebinary"
        android:text="Enter" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:entries="@array/DrawerItems" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Well, pretty much everything is shades of grey. Are you sure you just can't see them? Can you at least see "TextView" in white in the main content?

Comment: ive tried changing the color with no luck same result

Comment: This is what it looks like in the xml preview (how its supposed to look) https://gyazo.com/c89b3a15ad38ea36ce839b442de8f6c1 the next link is what it looks like when i load it up on my phone (lg g4) https://gyazo.com/cdd97af81328542a99043812a8670fd8

Comment: Dunno what to tell ya. That layout should work. Are you sure that's the layout that's being loaded? What's the name of that layout file? Are you calling `setContentView()` with `R.layout.` + that filename in the Activity? Does it display correctly when you run the app in an emulator?

Comment: i am calling setContentView() and its the only xml i have so it wouldnt be calling any other but i havent tried the emulator yet let me see what happens when i load it into the emulator

Comment: sadly same result on the emulator :(

Comment: Yeah, then I don't think that's the layout that's being loaded as the running Activity's main content. I just copied/pasted it, and it's fine. Please note that if you're using Android Studio, it now creates two XML layout files in your project by default. Make sure you've got the right one.

Comment: im not on android studio though im actually on eclipse, but its possible i messed something like that up so here's the oncreate method and a bit of the beginning of the class attached to the activity https://gyazo.com/20aa8b93a0bafc9f468682cfede21d20 https://gyazo.com/5ea9faedce185519d1ff3e6e2327d2bb

Comment: Yeah, never mind that rebuild. Your problem is the `if(savedInstanceState == null)` block. That  `FragmentTransaction` is hiding the main content in the layout's `LinearLayout`. Comment out that block, and run it again.

Comment: SUCCESS it worked perfectly what is that block anyways? it always generates that with oncreate.

Comment: anyways though thank you so much you have been very helpful!!

Comment: Yeah, that project uses Fragments for the DrawerLayout's main content. If you don't want to use Fragments, you can just remove all the Fragment-related code. It'll be easier to work with, especially if you're in the process of learning Android programming. Cheers!

Comment: Good to know thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else has this issue here was what fixed my issue "Yeah, never mind that rebuild. Your problem is the if(savedInstanceState == null) block. That FragmentTransaction is hiding the main content in the layout's LinearLayout. Comment out that block, and run it again." This answer was provided by Mike M Thanks again Mike for the help.